# Проблема получение данных с сайта

Tags: java, http

Занимаюсь получением http запроса, я вроде как пробился на сайт, но получаю след ошибки:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too 
 many times (20)
 at 
 java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLCo 
 nnection.java:1921)
 at 
 java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon nection.java:1509)
 at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1117)
 at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

ВОТ КОД:

```
    class Main {
        public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());

        URL url = new URL("");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String str;
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(str);
        }
        in.close();
        }
    }

class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            String promptString = getRequestingPrompt();
            System.out.println(promptString);
            String hostname = getRequestingHost();
            System.out.println(hostname);
            InetAddress ipaddr = getRequestingSite();
            System.out.println(ipaddr);
            int port = getRequestingPort();


            String username ="";
            String password ="";
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
        }
}
```

Пароль, логин и сайт я спец убрал!!!!

Comment: Возможно у вас проблемы с аутентификацией

Comment: Имеете ввиду не правильный логин и пароль? Если да, то пароль и логин правильный через браузер я спокойно зашел.

Comment: Вы не сбросили эту информацию, поэтому невозможно определить в чем у вас проблема.